# Delay in the middle of a script in Unity without calling a separate coroutine

Tags: c#, unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaitForSecondsExample : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(Example());
    }

    IEnumerator Example() {
        print(Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        print(Time.time);
    }
}
```

I don't like using functions in my code. Instead of the example above, I'd prefer:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaitForSecondsExample : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        print(Time.time);
    }
```

I can easily use yield In javascript but why can't I use yield in c# without using a function?

```
// Prints 0
print (Time.time);
// Waits 5 seconds
yield WaitForSeconds (5);
// Prints 5.0
print (Time.time);
```

I have many problem with using functions in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in C# too. You can use `IEnumerator Start()` instead of `void Start()`.

Comment: Neat! I didn't know you could use coroutines as the Monobehaviour message functions like Start, etc. Very elegant. :)

Comment: Yea, but not with every message method such as `OnDestroy`. Don't remember the whole list :P

Comment: I'm trying to find an official list of which ones do/don't support coroutines, both to add to the answer and for my own notes. So far I've only found [an unofficial thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/754968/can-monobehaviorstart-return-an-ienumerator-hint-y.html) reporting that `Awake`, `Update`, `LateUpdate`, `FixedUpdate`, `OnGUI`, `OnEnable`, `OnDisable`, `OnDestroy`, and `OnCollisionStay` cannot be used as coroutines, but I haven't verified all of these cases.

Comment: making sense with their names :). Well, please do let me know if you find anything official or confirm regarding this.

Answer (score -2):

from Unity Documentation :: [StartCoroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

> When using JavaScript it is not necessary to use StartCoroutine, the compiler will do this for you. When writing C# code you must call StartCoroutine.

Comment: would appreciate downvotes with a comment...

Comment: Patience, I'm still typing. ;) This answer is a bit misleading at present, bouncing between Java and Javascript, and making it sound like C# does not support threads - which of course it does. Coroutines are just another method to avoid holding up other work, even though they're still executed serially on the main thread.

Comment: oh ok, I understand what you are talking about ill remove that Java explanation since its relevant to this question.

Comment: The amended answer just talks about the syntax for calling the coroutine, ie. whether to write `StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint(2.0))` vs `WaitAndPrint(2.0)` - this is still calling a separate coroutine, and doesn't address OP's question about whether one can simply wait within the body of Start, without chaining to a separate coroutine.

Comment: well the unity documentation and the quote pretty much clarify the concept of coroutines and the appropriate way to use them, and workaround as suggested by Hazma are purely coding trick which not always the best way to code since it might defect/damage the programs functionality.

Comment: If you have evidence that using Start as a coroutine can cause harm, please present it — without this your comment is only speculation. The fact that the documentation shows one common use of coroutines does not imply that all other uses are invalid or discouraged. Meanwhile, the fact that Start can be used as a coroutine while OnDestroy can't looks to me like a deliberate feature the Unity engine developers created for cases like this, so I see no particular reason at present not to use it.